# Shade intersection of two disks with tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Is it possible to shade the intersection of two disks using tkz-euclide?

I am looking for something similar to the following simple example, but I need to shade *only* the intersection, while drawing the two circles' outlines in full.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)
\tkzDrawCircle[fill=blue,opacity=0.3](A,B)
\tkzDrawCircle[fill=blue,opacity=0.3](B,A)
\tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
\tkzDrawCircle(B,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: The `venndiagram` package should help.

Comment: @Bernard I am not creating Venn diagrams. I am looking to illustrate geometric ideas. This is a simplified example. The real figures have several other elements for which tkz-euclide is perfectly suited.

Comment: If it's not easily possible with tkz-euclide, that is also a useful answer. Then I'll know to look elsewhere (probably outside of LaTeX).

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `tkz-euclide`? Because it's pretty straightforward in plain Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @SebGlav I am not experienced with either tkz-euclide or TikZ. What I need is to be able to build on top of a figure created with tkz-euclide, and make use of the coordinates of some points created with tkz-euclide. I don't mind using other packages for as long as they can work together with tkz-euclide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely *need* to have it done with `tkz-euclide` only, here's a trick to be used. Find the two intersection points between the circles, then fill the two sectors between those points. You have to include it in a scope with `transparency group` if you want to apply some opacity to them.

[image: fill interCC]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
        \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)
        
        \tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A) \tkzGetPoints{K}{L}
        \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.5]
            \tkzFillSector[color=pink](A,L)(K)
            \tkzFillSector[color=pink](B,K)(L)
        \end{scope} 
            
        \tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
        \tkzDrawCircle(B,A)
        \tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
        \tkzDrawCircle(B,A)
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As a side note, you may probably know how to do it in plain Ti*k*Z:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\CA{(0,0) circle (3)}
        \def\CB{(3,0) circle (3)}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip \CA;
            \fill[pink,opacity=0.5] \CB;
        \end{scope}     
        \draw \CA \CB;
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces exactly the same design:

[image: fill intersection of circles]

Answer (score 3):

The solution with `tkz-euclide`is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)
\begin{scope}
  \tkzClipCircle(A,B)
  \tkzFillCircle[fill=blue,opacity=0.3](B,A)
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawCircles(A,B B,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Obviously, your solution is shorter, Alain. It seems that I didn't want to use `clip`, which I finally did in the plain Ti*k*Z solution ;)

Comment: My solution is identical to yours only the language is different

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth. Excellent, thank you! I will use this from now on, but I am a bit reluctant to change the accepted answer after several months, out of respect for the original answerer.

Comment: @Szabolcs The version 4 will arrive in a few days. SebGlav's solution is very good and interesting.